# При сохранение скрипта в VS, он не обновляется в Unity

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio-2019

Я пишу проект в Unity и столкнулся с проблемой, что при сохранение скрипта в Visual Studio, скрипт не обновляется в Unity. Подскажите пожалуйста как справиться с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Юнити работает с Visual Studio 2019 года, не знаю как у тебя, но у меня VS 2022, и прикол в том, что при установке Юнити новых версий автоматически скачивается VS 2019 года.

Вкратце: совместимость Юнити лучше с VS 2019 года